# Oracle strategy

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-12c, rman, data-synchronization

I would like to ask you to help me with following situation:

I have 2 servers. One is production and secondary is backup. Both are in 2 different geographical localizations. Switch between them in case of trouble with production is not essential. It could take max 1 hour.

Both servers have installed JBoss EAP 6.5 and Oracle 12c Std. edition. In case of problems with production server I have max 1 hour to switch to backup servers.
Production is being backuped on network drive during backup window between 10PM and 1AM.

How could I sort it out to have the latest data on backup server in case of troubles with production?
If I copy archive logs into external network drive then it could be problem that in case of failure with network drive my db will stop working.

PS
Upgrading Oracle into Oracle EE is not the way for me.

Comment: You need Enterprise Edition to use Oracle Data Guard, but it's possible to manually create a Data Guard-like system yourself. You've got to script the transferring, registering and application of archivelogs, but it's not too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you are running Windows or Linux, for the database i would have a non data guard standby, where you ship redo to the database throughout the day. Since you have standard edition, you can either use rsync or robocopy to incrementally copy the files that are not already there. If you run the commands from the standby server you can manually apply the archive logs to your standby database.

Regarding the web component, If you leave it shutdown you can incrementally copy over the configuration files. I'm not sure how clean that will be. Maybe you shutdown JBoss prod once per day and copy over everything that has changed. You should do some testing with that.